# RSpec throws a NoMethodError, but method works in the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method 'current_balance' defined in invoice.rb:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase
  has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :number, presence: true
  validates :currency, format: {with: /\A[A-Z]+\z/, message: "Please enter the 3 letter currency code in CAPS."}
  validates :total_due, presence: true
  validates :due_date, format: {with: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/, message: "format must be YYYY-MM-DD"}
  validates :status, presence: true

  def self.next_due
    where("due_date >= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 'Open').order("due_date DESC").first ? where("due_date >= ?", Time.now).order("due_date DESC").first.due_date : ''
  end

  def self.overdue
    where("due_date < ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 'Open').order("due_date DESC").first ? where("due_date < ?", Time.now).order("due_date DESC").first.due_date : ''
  end

  def current_balance
    self.current_balance = (self.total_due - self.payments.sum(:amount_paid))
  end

  def status
    if self.current_balance > 0
      then self.status = "Open"
    elsif self.current_balance < 0
      then self.status = "Overpaid"
    elsif self.current_balance = 0
      then self.status = "Paid"
    end
  end
end
```

The factory, invoices.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    sequence(:id) { |number| number }
    sequence(:purchase_id) { |n| n }
    number { FFaker::String.from_regexp(/\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\z/) }
    terms { FFaker::String.from_regexp(/\A[A-Za-z0-9\s]+\z/) }
    currency { FFaker::String.from_regexp(/\A[A-Z]+\z/) }
    total_due {'200.00'}
    due_date { FFaker::Time.date }
    notes { FFaker::HipsterIpsum.paragraph }
    status {[:open, :paid, :canceled].sample}
  end

  factory :invalid_invoice, parent: :invoice do
    currency nil
  end
end
```

The model spec, invoices_spec.rb contains:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Invoice, '#current_balance' do
  it "calculates the current balance of an invoice" do
    invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice, total_due: 200)
    invoice.payments << FactoryGirl.create(:payment, amount_paid: 100)
    invoice.payments << FactoryGirl.create(:payment, amount_paid: 50)
    expect(invoice.current_balance).to eq(50)
  end
end

describe Invoice do
  before(:all) { @invoice = FactoryGirl.build(:invoice) }
    it "has a valid factory" do
      expect(FactoryGirl.create(:invoice)).to be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a number" do
      invoice = Invoice.new(number: nil)
      expect(invoice).to_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a currency" do
      invoice = Invoice.new(currency: nil)
      expect(invoice).to_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a total_due" do
      invoice = Invoice.new(total_due: nil)
      expect(invoice).to_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a due_date" do
      invoice = Invoice.new(due_date: nil)
      expect(invoice).to_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a status" do
      invoice = Invoice.new(status: nil)
      expect(invoice).to_not be_valid
    end

end
```

The method works perfectly and calculates the current balance of an invoice when I run the app. When I run the model spec, however, I get an error.

The '#current_balance' & 'it has a valid factory' examples pass, the rest fail with the same error.

```
Failure/Error: expect(invoice).to_not be_valid
NoMethodError:
 undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the model validations.

Comment: Is `current_balance` an attribute on your `Invoice` model? In other words, do you have a database column for it?

Comment: @j-dexx I have edited my post to include the validations.

Comment: @raoul_dev Yes, current_balance is an attribute on my invoice model.

Comment: What callback is current balance set with?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I apologize, but I don't understand what you mean, my factory already sets total_due.

Comment: @j-dexx I don't have a callback set for current_balance. Should I have a callback set?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the model? Show the full code.

Comment: Turned out, I didn't need to see the factory, yet. But now that you posted it, why is `total_due` set as a string?

Comment: Without a callback how are you calling the code to calculate the current balance?

Comment: @j-dexx Do you mean in my spec, or in the actual app?

Comment: JFYI, you don't need the `then`s. Just remove them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for that information, I will remove them, old habits die hard I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, with the full model code the problem is crystal clear. It all starts with this line:

```
validates :status, presence: true
```

It triggers getter of `status`, which triggers getter of `current_balance` which sets `self.current_balance` by subtracting something from `total_due` which is not set (is `nil`) in all of those failing test cases. Hence the error message.

Comment: That was it exactly. Thank you Sir!